# TypeError: interpolate is not a function. react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to run react native app which build in class component, I update node module packages and react native to run but after it update it giving me error, yet app has no either type or syntax error

[image]

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 2 of react-native-reanimated

use interpolateNode() instead of interpolate()